# ArrayList sorted order lost strangely but why?

Tags: java, sorting

I have created a simple POJO Class Person and two comparators 'compareByValue' and 'compareByIndex' to sort the ArrayList of Person class. I start by sorting the ArrayList 'persons' and do a little filtering operation inside the loop of some other array. For the first pass it's okay but in the second pass of the loop ,immediately the order of Arraylist 'persons' is lost.
what's wrong with my code? the only operation done using ArrayList 'persons' is the subArray call does it destroy the ordering of the list?

```
class Result {
     static class Person
     {
        public Person(int index,int value){
            this.index=index;
            this.value=value;
        }

        int index;
        int value;

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }
    }

    public static Comparator<Person>compareByValue=new Comparator<Result.Person>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return o1.getValue()-o2.getValue();
        }
    };
    public static Comparator<Person>compareByIndex=new Comparator<Result.Person>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {

           return o1.getIndex()-o2.getIndex();
        }
    };

    public static int target(int targetValue,List<Person> persons)
    {
        int res=-1;
        int s=0;
        int  e=persons.size()-1;

        while(s<=e)
        {
            int m = (s+e)/2;
            if(persons.get(m).getValue()<targetValue){
                s=m+1;
            }else{
                res=m;
                e=m-1;
            }
        }
    return res;
}

public static List<Integer> kthPerson(int k, List<Integer> p, List<Integer> q) {

     List<Person> persons=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> queryRes=new ArrayList<>();

     for(int j=0;j<q.size();j++){
         queryRes.add(0);
     }

     for(int j=0;j<p.size();j++)
     {
         Person person=new Person(j,p.get(j));
         persons.add(person);
     }

    persons.sort(compareByValue);

    for(int j=0;j<q.size();j++)
    {
         int targetIndex=target(q.get(j).intValue(), persons);
         if(targetIndex==-1){continue;}

         if(persons.size()-targetIndex>=k)
         {
             List<Person> targetPersons=persons.subList(targetIndex, persons.size());
             targetPersons.sort(compareByIndex);
             queryRes.set(j, targetPersons.get(k-1).getIndex()+1);
         }
     }
        return queryRes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subList()` method does not change any order, but it also does not return a new list. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,int)):

> Returns a **view** of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural **changes in the returned list are reflected in this list**, and vice-versa. 
>   ...
>    (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

That means that if the order in the sub-list is changed, same is reflect in *main* list. If this is not wanted, create a copy of the returned sub-list:

```java
List<Person> targetPersons = new ArrayList(persons.subList(targetIndex, persons.size()));
```

<sub>I have not understood the algorithm of code posted in question, this answer is based mainly on questions text</sub>

Comment: is it possible to use Arrays.copyOfRange() for Arraylist ? I am not sure ... algorithm: I just want to find Persons whose values are higher or equal to target value and order to those values to get the first k values

Comment: sure, my bad; `Arrays.copyOfRange` only works for arrays - was too early - answer corrected